# Currency field displayed with different currency depending on language parameter in Visualforce page!

Tags: visualforce, bug, language

I recently got a problem when trying to use language parameter in my Visualforce pages. In a single currency org (French EUR, multi-currency feature not activated), if I set the language parameter to 'fr', I see a special character (see screenshot) displayed instead of '€' (which is correctly displayed when language is not set). More intriguing : if I set the language parameter to 'en_US', my currency fields (using apex:outputField) are displayed in... US DOLLAR!

- Language = en_US
  [image: language = en_US]
- Language = fr
  [image: language = fr]

Has anyone see this bug before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not find a value `fr` in the documentation - [`Supported Locales`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&language=en&type=0); but has following values:

> - French (Belgium): **fr_BE**
> - French (Canada):   **fr_CA**
> - French (Comoros):  **fr_KM**
> - French (France, Euro): **fr_FR_EURO**
> - French (France):   **fr_FR**
> - French (Guinea):   **fr_GN**
> - French (Haiti):    **fr_HT**
> - French (Luxembourg):   **fr_LU**
> - French (Mauritania):   **fr_MR**
> - French (Monaco):   **fr_MC**
> - French (Switzerland):  **fr_CH**
> - French (Wallis and Futuna):    **fr_WF**

Try using any of the country/region specific values to get proper currency using `apex:outputField`.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your response, that solved the issue related to the special character \o/ Now, € is correctly displayed when using fr_FR as language. Any idea/lead about the $ symbol displayed when setting language to en_US?

Comment: $ is currency used in United States, which is correct!

Comment: I see the default currency is US DOLLAR when setting the company locale to en_US, but not sure why this is impacting the currency fields (which should be based on the record currency...)

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, isn't that correct? Because the language attribute in visualforce also controls the locale for date, datetime, currency fields, etc respectively.

Comment: You're correct, the language attribute controls the locale for date, datetime, currency fields, etc. But it's supposed to control the format. For example, it helps us display 1,000.00 € for en_US users and 1 000,00 € for fr_FR users. In single currency org, we now see 1 000,00 € for fr_FR, but $ 1,000.00 for en_US users even though the record currency is EUR. Not sure if what I'm trying to say is very clear :)

Comment: Starting a new question would be better, please avoid asking multiple threads in one question.